# How to use defined variable out of function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a one signal javascript code and an ajax form, that give me a Player Id of the user in one signal,
so I want to use this code in my ajax login form and add the Player id to login form data, but i can't use a defined variable in one signal function, out of that and receive not defined message

```
OneSignal.push(function() {
        OneSignal.getUserId(function(userId) {
            var userid = userId;
        });
    });

    var options = {
        url: "{{CONFIG ajax_url}}/auth/login?hash_id=" + getHashID(),
        beforeSubmit:  function () {
            $('#output-errors').empty();
            $("#btn-submit").text("{{LANG Please wait..}}");
        }, 
        success: function (data) {
            $("#btn-submit").text("{{LANG Login}}");
            if (data.status == 200) {
                if ($('#page').attr('data-page') != 'home' && $('#page').attr('data-page') != 'forgot' && $('#page').attr('data-page') != 'reset') {
                    $('#main-header').html(data.header);
                    $('#login_box').modal('hide');
                    if (Amplitude.getActiveSongMetadata().price >= 0) {
                        location.href = window.location.href;
                    } else {
                        ajaxRedirect();
                    }
                } else {
                    location.href = window.location.href;
                }
            } else if (data.status == 400) {
                var errros = data.errors.join("<br>");
                $('#output-errors').html(errros);
            }
        },
        // here i add the one signal id
        data: {
            OSid: userid
        }
    };
    $('#login-form').ajaxForm(options);
```

Comment: Declare it in window scope

Comment: @SagarV I used this way but steel give not defined in console

Comment: You can move your `option` variable and `ajaxForm` call to the callback that you pass to `OneSignal.getUserId`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can solve this, here's one approach:

```
OneSignal.push(function() {
    OneSignal.getUserId(doAjax);
});

function doAjax(userId) {
    var options = {
        url: "{{CONFIG ajax_url}}/auth/login?hash_id=" + getHashID(),
        beforeSubmit:  function () {
            $('#output-errors').empty()
        ...
    }

    $('#login-form').ajaxForm(options);
}
```

The function `OneSignal.getUserId()` takes a function as an argument, so my solution declares a function `doAjax` that will take the userId as an argument, and then we pass that function to the `getUserId` function.

Comment: you're welcome.  This is a classic example of using the Functional Programming features of javascript.  The more you use it, the more you'll like it :).

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I suggest is:

```
Var userid;
OneSignal.push(function() {       
OneSignal.getUserId(function(userId) {
            userid = userId;
        });
    });
```